# Interface for Service class?

Tags: android

I want to implement my database helper class as a service, but it already extends SQLiteOpenHelper... is there an interface for Service available in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno if it is a good idea, but anyways, using inheritance does not make a lot of sense in this case - you should go with composition. Your service should extend Service class and include DatabaseHelper as an instance variable.